Show quantiles with stacked vertical lines over discrete axis in ggplot2
I am writing a paper and showing a lot of distributions which, of course, means a lot of box and violin plots. However, these can be boring and don't always show the full story of my data. I once saw a plot that used sets of lines stacked over discrete x values, where the y-axis is the value of a certain quantile of a certain quantile. The clustering of these quantiles along the y axis would then give indication as to the distribution. As an example:

The problem I have with this is that I don't like the continuous x-axis. A discrete x-axis would make labeling easier and enable other features I want to add to the plot. I know I could just do all of the labeling in post, but I think it would be cool to find a way within ggplot2. I'm still somewhat new to Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I need to clarify anything.
The code to construct the above graph is below. Note that I don't care about the data format or which geom_* is used, I would just like one of these plots with a discrete x axis.
library(ggplot2)

cutoffs <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)

a <- sqrt(seq(1, 10000, length.out = 100))
b <- (seq(1, 10, length.out = 100))^2
c <- seq(1, 100, length.out = 100) 

quant_data <- rbind(data.frame('class' = 'a',
                         'quantile' = quantile(a, probs = cutoffs)),
              data.frame('class' = 'b',
                         'quantile' = quantile(b, probs = cutoffs)),
              data.frame('class' = 'c',
                         'quantile' = quantile(c, probs = cutoffs)))

num_data <- data.frame('class' = c(rep('a', 100), rep('b', 100), rep('c', 100)),
                  'val' = c(a, b, c))

x_bases <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(x_bases) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')

quant_data$xmin <- x_bases[quant_data$class] - 0.2
quant_data$xmax <- x_bases[quant_data$class] + 0.2

num_data$xnum <- x_bases[num_data$class]

ggplot()+
  geom_linerange(data = quant_data, mapping = aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, y = quantile), linewidth = 2)


It's easier than you might think:
quant_data$xnum <- x_bases[quant_data$class]

ggplot(quant_data, aes(class, quantile)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = xnum - 0.2, xmax = xnum + 0.2))

You do have to be careful that xnum is correct, in the sense that is the same as the factor levels of class. So perhaps use this after_stat() method, to get the correct x-coordinate on the fly:
ggplot(quant_data, aes(class, quantile)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = after_stat(x) - 0.2, xmax = after_stat(x) + 0.2))

This would definitely be my preferred option.


Thank you for the answer, that worked great! Thank you to everyone else who responded as well, it was a great learning experience!

I think the easiest way to do this is to use vertical error bars, with the upper and lower values being the same. This allows you to directly plot the values over a categorical axis and specify the width of the lines without any other calculations:
library(ggplot2)

cutoffs <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)

a <- sqrt(seq(1, 10000, length.out = 100))
b <- (seq(1, 10, length.out = 100))^2
c <- seq(1, 100, length.out = 100) 

quant_data <- rbind(data.frame('class' = 'a',
                               'quantile' = quantile(a, probs = cutoffs)),
                    data.frame('class' = 'b',
                               'quantile' = quantile(b, probs = cutoffs)),
                    data.frame('class' = 'c',
                               'quantile' = quantile(c, probs = cutoffs)))

ggplot(quant_data, aes(y = quantile)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = class, ymax = quantile, ymin = quantile), 
                linewidth = 2, width = 0.5) +
  theme_gray(20)



If you treat the x-axis labels as factors it should resolve the problem
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


add_numeric = quant_data |>
  mutate(numeric_class = case_when(class == 'a' ~ 1,
                                  class == 'b' ~ 2,
                                 class == 'c' ~ 3))

 factor_labels  = ggplot()+
  geom_linerange(data = add_numeric, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(numeric_class), xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, y = quantile), linewidth = 2)

non_factor_labels = ggplot()+
  geom_linerange(data = add_numeric, mapping = aes(x = numeric_class, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, y = quantile), linewidth = 2)

library(patchwork)

factor_labels/non_factor_labels


Created on 2024-08-15 with reprex v2.1.1
